# Why can't I use an iterative variable in this struct function?

Tags: python

I want to convert every hex value I have to a float and I know that this:

```
while x < 7000:
    pos.append(struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(l[x]))[0])
    x+=1
```

works if I use a number instead of x, i.e. l(1) rather than l(x)
but when I use this code:

```
df4=pd.read_csv('indexedData.log', low_memory=False)
df4
import struct

l=df4['3']

pos=[]
x=0
while x < 7000:
    pos.append(struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(l[x]))[0])
    x+=1
pos
```

I get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-56-bede8a2bc9a3> in <module>()
          8 x=0
          9 while x < 7000:
    ---> 10     pos.append(struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(l[x]))[0])
         11     x+=1
         12 pos

ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

Comment: pro debugging tip: print variables out

Comment: If specific values for x work, there should be one (or more) bad pieces of data.  Did you try something like `print('{}: {!r}'.format(x, l[x]))` between lines 9 and 10?  If so, what happened?

Comment: o
131: '3dfc40ee'
132: '3befc406'
133: '0'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-454721530f52> in <module>()
      9 while x < 7000:
     10     print('{}: {!r}'.format(x, l[x]))
---> 11     pos.append(struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(l[x]))[0])
     12     x+=1
     13 pos

ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

Comment: I added the print statement as you said between lines 9 and 10 and appearantly a spot with '0' is not considered hexadecimal '0'. do you know how i can convert those too? or if necessary throw them out?